# GIT com multiplos remotes em um só projeto

Tags: php, git, arquitetura-de-software

Tenho o projeto A que é meu projeto principal. Desse projeto nasceu o projeto B, por "fork".
Maravilha, então eu quero desenvolver coisas no projeto A e quero replica-las para o projeto B.
Quando eu desenvolvo coisas no projeto A e commito push e tudo beleza, depois vou para o projeto B que eu clonei e adicionei um novo remote para ele:

```
git remote add upstream url_projeto
```

Eu faço:

```
git merge upstream/master
```

Maravilha, vem as alterações, MAS algumas coisas não estão vindo. Não sei pq, por exemplo uma pasta com seus respectivos arquivos não vieram.

E também em contra partida, eu desenvolvi coisas no projeto B que não existem no pai dele "projeto A" e quando eu do um merge no projeto B com o projeto A ele vai e deleta algumas coisas mesmo que elas nunca tenham existido no projeto A.

Ficou claro será o problema?

Answer (score 3):

Creio que não seja tão interessante trabalhar em dois dois projetos sobre 2 remotes. (E se eu compreendi o caso, o projeto **A** possui apenas 1 remote, enquanto o projeto **B** possui os dois). É possivel utilizar apenas 1 repositório com 2 remotes, mas exigirá *certo cuidado*.

Quando o codigo `git remote add upstream url_projeto` é executado, o git cria uma referencia interna para outro repositorio (Além do que já veio no clone), então é possivel ter **"n"** referencias. Exemplo:

Adicionando remote com referencia ao github:

`git remote add github https://github.com/userx/repox.git`

Adicionando remote com referencia ao bitbucket:

`git remote add bitbucket https://usex@y.z:1234/repox/repo.git`

Adicionando remote com referencia ao gitlab:

`git remote add gitlab http://gitlab.com/usex/repox.git`

Como pode ver, no exemplo citado eu criei 3 remotes para o mesmo projeto (*github*, *bitbucket*, *gitlab*), e portanto eu posso trabalhar com os 3 ao mesmo tempo.

Supondo que mais de uma pessoa tenha permissão apenas no github, enquanto outra que trabalha no gitlab precisa dessas modificações, mas você como intermediador do sistema precisa resolver a situação.

```
git fetch github master
git pull github
git push gitlab master
# Note que o remote sempre é especificado
```

Pronto, agora gitlab foi atualizado com o conteudo do github. Mas mesmo assim ainda é bem complicado de gerenciar essas alterações desta forma... Recomendo que tente trabalhar apenas com um remote, pois é possivel que ocorra muitos problemas, por exemplo conflitos em que apenas o administrador possa soluciona-los.

Comment: Opa obrigado pela resposta. É dessa forma que estou usando já, como sou administrador dos 2 projetos não tem problema. Só esse bug bizarro onde certos arquivos que são criados no projeto pai (no caso o A) quando dou pull ele não vem para o projeto B e não sei porque isso.